# Show text one time using ng-repeat with condition

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to show element only one time within `ng-repeat`.

My code bellow doesn't work because "Event of today" is shown each time when an event is starting today...

My code :

```
  <div class="line" ng-repeat="event in events">
    <!-- h4 only once if condition is passed -->
    <h4 ng-if="event.start.getTime() === today.getTime()">Event of today</h4>
    <!-- h4 only once if condition is passed -->
    <h4 ng-if="event.start.getTime() === tomarrow.getTime()">Event of tomarrow</h4>
    <div class="event-body">
      <a href="/event/show/{{event.id}}" class="event-title"><h3>{{event.categoryName}} : {{event.title}}</h3></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want it to select one thing to display from the iteration, or you only want any given iteration to appear once, even when there are duplicates?

Comment: I only want things to appear once... Yes even if there is duplicates...

Comment: Can you use `ng-if`?

Comment: Yes I can but `ng-if` is repeated each time in the `ng-repeat`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a filtered version of the events array and display that. You can make a function that refilters it, and call that whenever there's a change that needs it to update (putting it in a `$scope.$watch` function seems the easiest way to do this). It seems low-tech, but it really gives you the most control over what you end up seeing.

Here is a very stripped-down Plunker of this, just showing some simple filtering: [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/k9a8YNjRsDtChrcs3O0O?p=preview).